# Creating a mysql cloud

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm trying to find a solution for creating a small mysql cloud. I don't need it for storage, it's more for reliability. Is it possible to have 2 identical mysql servers and if one goes down the other is still working and will sync when it comes back online? The idea is kinda like a RAID-1 setup, but intead of HDDs I want to use two whole servers.

Is there a solution like this out there? I was looking at onapp, but it may not work well with mysql.

Comment: have you look at master-slave and mysql replication. are you actually setting up your own cloud, or looking for a service that offers this functionality already

Comment: It's called [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using MySQL replication.
- using active-pasive with [rdbd](http://www.drbd.org/) + [heartbeat](http://linux-ha.org/wiki/Heartbeat)

In any case you would need use DNS to automatically update the IP or VIP

Answer (score 1):

What you want is MySQL [Master-Master replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html), which will work as you request.

Answer (score 1):

We did this once with 6 mysql servers doing replication in a circular chain. The replication chain was:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> A
```

When a failover was detected the master was moved from A to B (an so forth) - DNS was updated for the master - but reads where taken from random member of the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You want [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html). There are a number of ways to set it up; have a look at that doc.